# Python is not detecting a substring, even though it is there (the string is from the output of argparse)

Tags: python, argparse

I have a string (which is the output when you put in `python parser.py foo` and using argparse) which is:
[image: argparse]

(sidenote: I have checked to see if it is a string, and it is.)

And so, I'm trying to see if the word foo is in this string. So, I'm using

```
print("foo" in argparse_string_output)
```

And obviously, this should output True. But this outputs False, and I don't know why. Please help!

---

Code:
parser.py

```
import argparse

def create_parser():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command -h', dest='command')

  add_parser = subparsers.add_parser("add", help="add -h")

  return parser

if __name__ == "__main__":
  create_parser().parse_args()
```

File which contains the in statement (which is named readout.py)

```
import os


def runargs(cmd):
  newcmd = ["python", "parser.py"] + cmd
  return os.popen(" ".join(newcmd)).read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  x = runargs(["foo"])
  print(x)
  print(x, "foo" in x)
```

---

My full code is at GitHub (I have simplified it here, as the path that I told you I put in is false). It is here: [Github link](https://github.com/CrazyVideoGamez/auto-backup). Also, the real command to get this output was `python tests/readout.py`

Comment: possibly you are checking in stdout and your text is in stderr. what do you see when you just do `print(argparse_string_output)`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri When I print the string, I get the output shown in the image, and this is because I **printed** the stdout in the console. Also, I checked the output when I run the parser.py python file with the correct arguments, and it was the same as the string

Comment: From all my experience, if the line `print("foo" in argparse_string_output)` produces `False`, then the three characters `foo` do not exist as a substring in the string referenced by `argparse_string_output`.  I would like to see the output from the statement `print(argparse_string_output, "foo" in argparse_string_output)`. - Better yet, can you please supply a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Steve I ran it, and it basically just shows the same thing but with argparse_string_output in the beginning

Comment: Show us.  Add the minimal code necessary to produce the issue to your question so that others can see if they can reproduce your result. - I don't want to take the time to figure out what's in GitHub.  Maybe someone else will.  But if you don't get the answer this way, I would suggest following the S.O. guidelines and add the necessary code to your question to allow others to reproduce your problem with a simple copy/paste into their editor or IDE.  Supplying code via a GitHub repo technically takes your question out of scope for S.O. as it violates the guidelines.

Comment: @Steve I'll edit the answer to include parse.py, and the checker file that runs the in statement

Comment: No matter what the problem is, I don't know how to help you from what you've given us so far.  If we can reproduce it, I expect someone will be able to tell you what's happening.

Comment: Condense your code down to a _small_ self-contained example that we can copy and run ourselves.

Comment: If `parse.py` is self-contained, then sure, that should do it. - If not...then what @JohnGordon said.

Comment: If it isn't self-contained, then _make a version that is_.  Remove all the fancy options and such, leaving only the code that directly demonstrates the problem, and then post that code here in the question.

Comment: @JohnGordon and Steve Ok I think provided the code now

Comment: The output you're seeing is the parser stderr.  It is _not_ from your print statement.  `print(x)` is empty.

Comment: oof this question is -1

Comment: Can someone reopen this? I added the minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the output you're hoping to grab is going to stderr rather than stdout, and you're grabbing stdout.  Here's what I get when I run your code:

```
01:58:51 (dev3) steve@US-ST032JO-MLT blah ±|master ✗|→ python foo.py
usage: parser.py [-h] {add} ...
parser.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'add')

 False
```

If, on the other hand, I modify your code to redirect stderr to stdout like this:

```
def runargs(cmd):
  newcmd = ["python", "parser.py"] + cmd + ['2>&1']
  return os.popen(" ".join(newcmd)).read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  x = runargs(["foo"])
  print(x)
  print(x, "foo" in x)
```

then I get the behavior I think you're expecting:

```
01:59:11 (dev3) steve@US-ST032JO-MLT blah ±|master ✗|→ python foo.py
usage: parser.py [-h] {add} ...
parser.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'add')

usage: parser.py [-h] {add} ...
parser.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'add')
 True
```

Were you maybe confused by seeing the output being written to the console by Python itself and thinking that that was coming from your `print()` statement?  As you can see here, your `print()` statement will print a second copy of the output if the code is working like you expect.

Comment: Yeah this is correct

Comment: I feel like deleting this question now lol

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad we could get that straight for you.  Console output can be confusing.